# Per mille (‰) symbol causes div innerHTML to automatically break line (Javascript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, newline, symbols

The per mille(`‰`) symbol causes the string in innerHTML to automatically break the line. I really don't know why it does that. What makes it more unusual is that other symbols like `*`,`&`,`^`,`%`,`$` works just fine. does the per mille symbol mean something else in HTML or Javascript?

Here is the style of the div:

`style='text-align: left; padding-left: 12px; color: white;position:absolute; width:600px; left:52px; overflow:hidden;'`

The text to be placed for example is:

```
WWWWWWWWWWW‰WW‰‰‰‰WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW‰‰%‰WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

This is what happens: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uSAO.jpg)

usually it should occupy only one line since there is an overflow:hidden on the style but for some reason it breaks into lines after the per mille symbol. Does anybody have an idea why it does this?

**[EDIT]**: I forgot to mention that the string that is placed on the div came from the servlet (java).

Comment: nothing to do with java

Comment: EDIT: Still nothing to do with java

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `‰`: Within a fixed width container, the browser avoids to break words, so long words will jump to the next line. You can force the browser to break words by using `word-break:break-all;`.

Demo :https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/0h2f2yxj/

I hope this will help you.